# Redshift COPY command - values for some fields did not copy across

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I've created a staging table which I would like to populate from a JSON file in S3 bucket using the COPY command. It worked but values for `firstName`, `itemInSession`, `lastName`, `sessionId`, `userAgent`, `userId` were not copied across.

**table.py**

```
from dwh_conn import *

drop_staging_event = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS staging_event;"

create_staging_event = ("""
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS staging_event(
    artist VARCHAR,
    auth VARCHAR,
    firstName VARCHAR,
    gender TEXT,
    itemInSession INTEGER,
    lastName VARCHAR,
    length FLOAT,
    level TEXT,
    location VARCHAR,
    method TEXT,
    page TEXT,
    registration FLOAT,
    sessionId INTEGER,
    song VARCHAR,
    status INTEGER,
    ts BIGINT,
    userAgent VARCHAR,
    userId VARCHAR
    );""")

load_staging_event = ("""COPY staging_event FROM 's3://dwh-training/data/log_data/2018/11/'
    credentials 'aws_iam_role={}' region 'us-east-2' JSON 'auto';""").format(ROLE_ARN)
```

The following returned empty rows:

```
SELECT firstName, itemInSession, lastName, sessionId, userAgent, userId FROM staging_event LIMIT 5;
 firstname | iteminsession | lastname | sessionid | useragent | userid 
-----------+---------------+----------+-----------+-----------+--------
           |               |          |           |           | 
           |               |          |           |           | 
           |               |          |           |           | 
           |               |          |           |           | 
           |               |          |           |           | 
(5 rows)
```

But other fields have values:

```
SELECT artist, auth, gender, length, level, location, method, page, registration, song, status, ts FROM staging_event LIMIT 5;
          artist           |   auth    | gender |  length   | level |         location         | method |   page   | registration  |              song               | status |      ts       
---------------------------+-----------+--------+-----------+-------+--------------------------+--------+----------+---------------+---------------------------------+--------+---------------
 N.E.R.D. FEATURING MALICE | Logged In | M      |  288.9922 | free  | New Orleans-Metairie, LA | PUT    | NextSong | 1541033612796 | Am I High (Feat. Malice)        |    200 | 1541121934796
                           | Logged In | F      |           | free  | Lubbock, TX              | GET    | Home     | 1540708070796 |                                 |    200 | 1541122176796
 Death Cab for Cutie       | Logged In | F      | 216.42404 | free  | Lubbock, TX              | PUT    | NextSong | 1540708070796 | A Lack Of Color (Album Version) |    200 | 1541122241796
 Tracy Gang Pussy          | Logged In | F      | 221.33506 | free  | Lubbock, TX              | PUT    | NextSong | 1540708070796 | I Have A Wish                   |    200 | 1541122457796
 Skillet                   | Logged In | M      | 178.02404 | free  | Harrisburg-Carlisle, PA  | PUT    | NextSong | 1540006905796 | Monster (Album Version)         |    200 | 1541126568796
(5 rows)
```

Does anyone know why the empty fields were not being populated? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banty - Redshift COPY with "json 'auto'" will only load json values that it can match with the table.  This can be done on column name matching top json keys but they need to match exactly.  Check that these names match EXACTLY.

A better way to match things up is to use a json_paths file that maps the json keys to the Redshift columns.  Name changes can be made there as well as loading data from non-top-level json keys.

This is just the most common reason that this happens that I know about.  If you need more info reply and you will likely need to provide an except of the json you are loading.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Before posting the question, I checked that the column names matched the top json keys but didn't work. Using a json path file for mapping as you pointed out solves the problem.